# Change windows name for Android Studio to remove space.

Tags: android, windows, windows-10

I am just getting into android app development and I accidentally named my computer with my first and last name separated by a space. However, the Android SDK does not like that and says it does not like spaces as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5AkXH.png).

Is it possible to change the name of my computer? Changing the username does not help and neither does changing the computer name.

Answer (score 2):

You do not have to change your computer name, you can include an underscore instead of a space (_) for Android Studio, it can be a little picky. To change your computer's name if you still want to, go to My Computer, locate "Change Settings" and type in your new name for your computer. Alternatively go to System(can be reached by going to your start menu), and simply go to "Rename PC" if you are on Windows 10. Keep in mind you might have to restart your computer.